# I keep getting segmentation fault :11 errors and i can't figure out why... c++

Tags: c++

This program compiles alright but sometimes it creates segmentation errors.

The program should let the user to input student names, marks obtained for theory(70%) and practical papers(30%). These data should be saved into a file and finally the program should display/store student's name and marks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void disp(int);
using namespace std;
void stunames(int n) {

    int count = 0;
    string names;

    cout << "Input student names :" << endl;
    ofstream na("names.txt");

    while( count <= n ) {

        getline(cin,names);
        na << names << endl;
        count++;
    }
    na.close();
}
void theomarks(int size) {

    double marks;
    int count = 0;
    ofstream tho("T.txt");

    while( count < size ) {
        cin >> marks;
        if((marks > 100) ||(marks < 0)){
            cout << "Invalid marks, Re-enter" << endl;
            count = count-1;
        }
        else
            tho << marks*.7 << endl;
        count++;
    }

    tho.close();

}
void pracmarks(int size) {

    ofstream pr("P.txt");
    double marks;
    int count = 0;

    while( count < size ) {

        cin >> marks;
        if((marks > 100) ||(marks < 0)){
            cout << "Invalid marks, Re-enter" << endl;
            count = count-1;
        }
        else
            pr << marks*.3 << endl;
        count++;
    }
    pr.close();
}


void calc(int size) {

    ifstream na("names.txt");
    ifstream readr("T.txt");
    ifstream mo("P.txt");
    string x;
    double pracc[1][size];
    double theory[1][size];
    cout << "NAME\t\tMARKS" << endl;

    for(int row = 0; row < size; row++) {

        for(int col = 0; col < 1; col++) {

            mo >> pracc[row][col];
            readr >> theory[row][col];
            na >> x;
            cout << x << "\t\t" << theory[row][col]+pracc[row][col];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    readr.close();
    mo.close(); 
    na.close();
}

int main() {

    int no;     
    cout << "Input the number of student: " << endl;
    cin >> no;
    stunames(no);
    cout << "Input Theory Paper Marks" << endl;
    theomarks(no);
    cout << "Input practical Paper Marks" << endl;
    pracmarks(no);
    calc(no);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: row and col look mixed up.

Comment: The best investment you can make as a student in programming is spend some time learning to use a debugger and becoming proficient at it.  Donald Knuth, a legendary programmer, was once asked what is his favorite computer language, his answer "one that has a good debugger."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing

```
mo>>pracc[row][col];
```

But your array is defined:

```
double pracc[1][size];
```

and `row` goes above 1. So you're going past the boundary of the array. You probably want

```
double pracc[size][1];
```

Comment: No, double prac[1][size] means the size of the array 2* size , prac[1 ][size]={{21},{67},....n}; etc

Comment: The fact is that your loop accesses pracc[row][col], and row goes above 1, so your array definition is wrong. Or you could keep the array definition the same and do pracc[col][row]. Either way works.

Comment: Please remember to upvote the answer and click the checkmark if this answer is "correct". It lets other people know the question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

In expression pracc[row][col]; row and col ranges are messed up. Row must be less than 1;
It would be better to use ::std::array instead of C-style arrays. It would give you a proper debug assertion at corresponding moment instead of sudden segmentation fault.